# Doing an efficient update in batches using Backup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I've got some data which I've backed up from tableA. so I did this by doing the following:-

```
select * into backuptable_tableA from tableA
where column1= 'Value1' and column2 = 'Value2'
```

The backup consists of about 185,000 rows and as shown above is called backuptable_tableA

Now within tableA I need to update 1 column (column1) with the value 'LAMK'. Now can anyone suggest an efficient SQL query which can update column1 in tableA but in batches. Let's say 10,000 rows at a time? The SQL should stop after updating the first 10,000 and then I can check the data and do the next 10,000 and so on... also anyway of ensuring it does this by joining to the backuptable_tableA? (For arguments sake let's say tableA as a unique constraint of column1, column2, column3 and column4).

..Or would I have to use the same parameters in the update I used when doing the backup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that's worked for me in the past using a while loop
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178642.aspx

```
set rowcount 10000
declare @rc int
set @rc =1 
while @rc !=0
begin

  update TableA set column1 = 'LAMK'
    where column1 != 'LAMK'
      and column2  = ... 
      and column3  = ... 
      and column4  = ...
  select @rc = @@rowcount
end
go
```

You can add checks inside the loop and rollback the transaction as needed.

HTH